# Error in Connectivity of SQLSERVER2008 database?

Tags: java, database, jsp

i want to connect my jsp page with database of server SQLSERVER.
server i am using is "subversion\subfolder" of SQLSERVER.
when i tried with subversion its working fine but when i am trying to connect it with `subfolder its throwing error like=="java.sql.SQLException: Unknown server host name 'subversionsql2k8'"`

and following is my connectivity code with java,let me know whats wrong with the following code

Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

```
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://subversion
\\subfolder/table_name","username","password");
```

Thanks in Advance---

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with jdbc url

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://subversion\\subfolder/table_name
```

- Can you check the host name, is it correct ?  is it reachable from the machine ?
- what is subfolder/table_name ?

Comment: did you mean `//subversion\\sql2k8/career ` is the host name ?

Comment: nopes sql2k8 is name of subfolder and career is d name of table...do u have any idea to resolve this problem??

Comment: @Smith which version, isn't SQL2008 Express?

Comment: URL should be of the form `jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;DatabaseName=dbname`